# Is there a way to force update Microsoft Office Personal 2019 via the command line?

Tags: microsoft-office, windows-update, microsoft-office-2019

I can't find a way to force update Microsoft Office Personal 2019 via the command line.

Normally when office has problems updating I try running the officec2rclient.exe updater executable. However, I can't find it anywhere.

Here are the locations I've checked for officec2rclient.exe:

- `%PROGRAMFILES%\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\officec2rclient.exe`
- `%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Common Files\microsoft shared\ClickToRun\officec2rclient.exe`

I also checked scheduled tasks, but Office Automatic Updates 2.0 task doesn't seem to exist anymore. (The `%WINDIR%\System32\Tasks\Microsoft\Office` directory doesn't exist.)

Does Office 2019 click-to-run use officec2rclient.exe for updating? 
If not, what is the method to force Office 2019 click-to-run to check for updates via the command line?

!!NOTE!!

I was finally able to update this version of office. It turns out there was a group policy setting causing trouble:

`Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Windows Update > Configure Automatic Updates > Install updates for other Microsoft products`

After marking the checkbox for `Install updates for other Microsoft products` the Office installation was able to update normally.

However, the original question regarding how to update Office 2019 via the command line has still not been answered, so I will keep this question open until there is a solution.

Comment: Why do you believe you need to find and/or run `officec2rclient.exe`?  Are you running a 64-bit or 32-bit version of Windows?  Likewise, do you have a 32-bit or 64-bit version of Office installed?  The command would be `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun\OfficeC2RClient.exe /update user updatepromptuser=true forceappshutdown=true displaylevel=true`

Comment: Because with other versions of office that are having problems updating I've usually found success updating using officec2rclient.exe. Also, the office installation in question is located remotely. For this particular installation the `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ClickToRun` folder is missing.

Comment: If you had a 32-bit version of Office installed on a 64-bit OS the correct folder would be Program Files X86

Comment: Based on my research, there is a scheduled task named **“Office Automatic Updates 2.0 ”** for C2R versions of Office, it could check updates automatically via running OfficeC2RClient.exe. Maybe you could go to Task Scheduler check whether there is this scheduled task [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfbzV.jpg), then check the path of OfficeC2RClient.exe.

Comment: @EmilyHua The scheduled task doesn't seem to exist... I updated details above.

Comment: Could you please open one Office application, go to `File > Account > Update Options`? Please check whether you could click Updates Now. If not, please refer to [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/troubleshoot/updates/automatic-updates). When nothing helps, you may try to **repair Office** to have a check. You could also try to update to specific version via `setup.exe /configure` command and Configuration file (.xml file) [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/configuration-options-for-the-office-2016-deployment-tool#version-attribute-part-of-add-element).

Comment: What?  You have an Office Insider build installed?  Can you provide a screenshot minus license information?  Have you used Search within File Explorer to try and find officec2rclient.exe?

Comment: @EmilyHua there doesn't seem to be any place to update office at File > Account > Update Options. There are Office Insider related options, options to view version information, and licence updating options, but that is fairly much it.

Comment: @Ramhound There is an Office Insider button with various options for joining the Office Insider program. The GUI is not in English so I'm not sure posting a screenshot would help.

Comment: Just provide a translation to English

Comment: @Ramhound Okay, it probably says something like "Office Insider - Join the Office Insider program and get early access to new releases of Office."